# Scale coordinates on radar

Tags: java, android, math, gps, location

I'm currently developing an radar for android. (Following this tutorial: http://www.androidph.com/2009/02/app-10-beer-radar.html )

I'm getting all users within a range of 5KM around my current location from the server after that I draw in my customview like this:

```
float xU = (float)(userLocation.getLongitude() + getWidth() / 2 - currentLong);
float yU = (float)(getHeight() / 2 - userLocation.getLatitude() + currentLat);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmpUser,xU,yU,radarPaint);
```

Now my problem is, that I need to scale the the points / coordinates I draw on the radar, because all users within a distance below 5KM will be drawn like only 2-3 Pixel away from the center. How would I manage to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it. All you need to do is to set the value of the "scale" variable to the required value;

```
float scale = 3.0f; //set this to any number to change the drawing scale

float xU = (float)(getWidth() / 2 + (userLocation.getLongitude() - currentLong) * scale);
float yU = (float)(getHeight() / 2 - (userLocation.getLatitude() - currentLat) * scale);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmpUser,xU,yU,radarPaint);
```

Comment: Nice, that actually fixed the problem that every dot was neard the center, but how can I increase the distance between the coordinates I draw?

Comment: How do you draw the coordinates? Can you share that piece of code as well?

Comment: I just use canvas.drawBitmap and draw a bmp on the X/Y coordinates

Comment: I still need the source code because I can imagine many ways of drawing coordinates the way you described.

Comment: I don't do anything beside the things I do in my OP in my custom view to draw them

Comment: If you don't do anything beside the things you do in your OP and I have already addressed your OP and provided a solution then it means you should be able to apply the same solution to drawing coordinates. If you can't apply the same solution to drawing coordinates then it means you are doing something different when drawing coordinates and I need to see it to provide another solution.