# How can I plot locations around a point on a canvas or chart (radar like) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have location data which returns latitude,longitude and also distance and heading(angle) from a given center point. For example if I search for ATMs around me it returns data around me like

```
{
  location:[30.66,81.65],
  distance: 500,
  heading: 122 
},
{
  location:[30.69,81.65],
  distance: 600,
  heading: 123
}
```

Now I want to plot this data onto a canvas with my location as center and all other points on radar like canvas or chart.

Comment: For each ATM you could solve for your position like this: `var pos=[atm.location[0]-cos(heading)*distance
atm.location[1]-sin(heading)*distance]`. Hopefully each ATM will return the same position for you (otherwise something is wrong with the data). Now you can figure out the ATM's position relative to you with `[atm.location[0]-pos[0], atm.location[1]-pos[1]]`

Comment: It doesn't look like the problem is getting x and y from heading and distance as he has long/lat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scale coordinates on radar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196151/scale-coordinates-on-radar)

Comment: @RoyFalk Yeah that part confused me, because there is a surplus of information. Maybe the OP wants to rotate and scale everything so all the conditions are met?